# Android - Is there a way to use recyclerview.addOnScrollListener as a function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This code is used on pages with lists. Since this code is redundant on all pages, I would like to use it bundled up in a function. Is there a way??

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val lastVisibleItemPosition =
                    (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                val itemTotalCount = recyclerView.adapter!!.itemCount-1

                if (lastVisibleItemPosition == itemTotalCount && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && !lastPageCheck) {
                    // something 
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kotlin extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically).
You might have to consider handling the global variable(`lastPageCheck`) though.

Something like this

```
fun RecyclerView.onScrollChangeCustom(doSomething: () -> Unit) {
addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        val lastVisibleItemPosition =
            (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
        val itemTotalCount = (recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0) - 1

        if (lastVisibleItemPosition == itemTotalCount && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && !lastPageCheck) {
            doSomething()
        }
    }
})
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much. Sharing your knowledge solved the problem.